# Codeigniter routing throws 404 page not found error

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-3

When I am using url as

`mysite.com/index.php/user/user`  the method is getting called.

But when I add below line in `routes.php` so that I can access the function using custom url.
it is throwing me error.  `404 Not Found`

I want to access the method using url as `mysite.com/user`

`$route['user']['get'] = 'user/user';`

`user.php` is present inside controller directory

```
    <?php
    use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    require APPPATH . 'libraries/REST_Controller.php';
    require APPPATH . 'libraries/Format.php';

    class User extends REST_Controller {

        function __construct()
        {
            // Construct the parent class
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function user_get(){
            $this->set_response("request recieved", REST_Controller::HTTP_OK); // OK (200) being the HTTP response code
        }
    }
```

**[2nd question]**

how to make a route to access the controller present inside certain folders in controller directory.

suppose a controller file is present in `controllers/api/v1/` directory with file name `user.php`

**Note:**
I have tried all the solutions given by users on other posts but issue was not resolved.

---

**EDIT: Issue Resloved**

Routing is working just fine now. I think the problem was, I was calling mysite.com/user , instead I should have called mysite.com/index.php/user

Second issue of index.php being in the url is also resolved.
I was making the changes in `.htaccess` file which was present in `Application` folder instead.
I created a `.htaccess` file in `root folder` then added below mentioned line of code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: is `User.php` in a subfolder called `user` i.e. `controllers/user/Users.php`? are you attempting to access `user` with a get request?

Comment: no. `User.php` file is located inside `controllers` folder i.e,  `controllers/User.php`.  yes I am trying to access with a get request.

Comment: 1) Are you trying to get rid of `index.php` from the URL, or trying to add a route? You haven't shown us [the `.htaccess` update required to get rid of `index.php`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file). Do one thing at a time. 2) I think using verbs in controller method names used to be supported in CodeIgniter, but [it is not mentioned in the docs anymore](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#using-http-verbs-in-routes) - have you tried using just `user()` as your method name?

Comment: 3) If you're still having trouble, start simple - get rid of `REST_Controller.php`, get rid of `Format.php`, remove the `__construct()` which does nothing, have your method just return some plain text ...

Comment: I tried using the function named user(), but that was not being called with the get request, i am trying to remove index.php from url and also add a custom route .

Answer (score 0):

You have set your route as

```
$route['user']['get'] = 'user/user';
```

Which is directing to the user controller and the user method. But in your controller you have a method called `user_get`.

So the simplest fix here is to change your route to point to the correct method.
**NOTE: You have no method called 'user' so why is that in the route?**

So this...

```
$route['user']['get'] = 'user/user'; // the user method does not exist
```

Would become...

```
$route['user']['get'] = 'user/user_get'; // the user_get method does exist
```

**Update: To remove index.php from your URL, your .htaccess might be**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And make sure you add in your base_url in **applications/config/config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com';  // Change to your sites URL
$config['index_page'] = '';  // remove index.php
```

Comment: I have tried this solution , it doesn't work. I am calling `mysite.com/user`.  for some reasons I'm still getting 404 error.

Comment: @VickySalunkhe It does work - I have tested it not ever having used http verbs in routes before now... I have added in something to help relieve you of your index.php issue. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Hi Tim as you told, I have copied the code in .htaccess file present in `Application` folder. and checked the `config` file also, but still not able to access without index.php in url and problem in routing method is still there.

Comment: routing is working just fine now. I think the problem was, I was calling `mysite.com/user` , instead I should have called `mysite.com/index.php/user`  , so now the question remains 1) how to remove index.php from url.

Comment: The ,htaccess file with the code I provided needs to be in the folder where your index.php resides. It sounds like you changed the one in your application folder. That is not the correct spot. Sorry I wasn't more specific. If you don t have one there you will need to create it